# Printing an image in Netbeans/Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I am creating a program for an online class at school where I have to print a specified amount, shape, and color of balloons to... well I don't know what to print it too. There was no information in the notes before it on where i print pictures of balloons to and i've learned nothing about displaying a picture or about gui's.I'm lost and have no clue what to do. Please Help :)

Here is what I was assigned to do:

Write the necessary Java source code.

Write the Java source code necessary to build a solution for the following problem:

You have been asked by the local first grade parents' group to create a software package that helps them to teach their children colors. To that end, you have decided to create a program called "Balloons" that allows the child to enter in the number of balloons and the color of each. Then, your program will draw that many balloons on the screen and color them the correct color. You should create a "draw balloon" method that draws the requested number of balloons on the screen. Each balloon should be colored the correct color. Initially, all of the balloons should be created as circles. Next, you should allow the child to select a shape for each balloon and draw the correct number of balloons with the correct shape and color. Before you create this program, create a formal storyboard for it. Rather than writing a new method for "draw balloon" when the shape changes, reuse the initial method.

Comment: [here](http://binkster.hubpages.com/hub/Programming-Basic-2D-Shapes-in-Java-Using-Graphics-and-JFrame-Classes) is an easy tutorial for painting forms on a canvas in Java. The examples there will create basic GUI Frames and paint circles, rectangles etc.. maybe you want to start there. Once you have a small program that opens a window where you paint a simple circle, you can think about extending that program and adding two circles, circles with colors etc. Then you should start thinking about how you could add an input field and a button so that the children can enter numbers.

Comment: The link is blocked on my schools network but i will check it out when I get home, thanks for the help.

Comment: well you can easily search for other tutorials. just google `java canvas circle` or follow the link from stevietheTV's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no requirement on you to print on any specific place, my guess is that you should use Swing (this was a quick google: http://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/basicdrawing/).

Create a baseclass that is a ballon. Maybe do subclasses of this or implement an interface with shape or something similar. I guess the idea is that the draw-funciton should be generic enough so no matter what shape your class implements it should have enough information to draw that shape

Try to boil it down and make a story of each small task and voila, you are finished.